# What are the differences between the CRCNA position on infallibility and the ICBI position on inerrancy?

Tags: bible, inerrancy, infallibility, biblical-reliability

The [International Committee on Biblical Inerrancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Statement_on_Biblical_Inerrancy) has set out two magisterial documents related to an understanding of inerrancy: the [Chicago Statement on Biblical Inerrancy](http://www.bible-researcher.com/chicago1.html) (1978) and the [Chicago Statement on Biblical Hermeneutics](http://www.bible-researcher.com/chicago2.html) (1981). Earlier (1959), the Christian Reformed Church of North America settled on a definition and understanding of [Biblical infallibility](https://www.crcna.org/welcome/beliefs/position-statements/bible-inspiration-infallibility). [According to one member](http://www.thebanner.org/features/2011/09/how-should-we-read-the-bible) of the Council on Infallibility:

> The committee discussed at some length the usefulness of the word inerrant to describe the Bible. We concluded that it is not the most felicitous term to express the unique character of the Scriptures. We agreed that infallible and trustworthy fit the nature of the Bible more appropriately.

The rest of his article speaks in general terms on why they rejected the term, but I'm looking for more than that. I'd like to understand specifically what about the reliability and authority of the Bible the ICBI affirms and denies that the CRCNA would not affirm and deny, and vice-versa.

Comment: The references of CRCNA articles are giving 1968 onwards not 59. It seems the link you gave is showing the later reformed definition like the Chicago one. There seems to be no difference between the two. The CRCNA is more explicitly allowing scientific and metaphoric interpretation; https://www.crcna.org/welcome/beliefs/position-statements/bible-authority whereas Chicago statements are not so explicit on this area. Both are essentially same in not limiting a particular interpretation in defining inerrancy or infallibility.

Comment: `The references of CRCNA articles are giving 1968 onwards not 59. It seems the link you gave is showing the later reformed definition like the Chicago one.` Not sure what you mean. The link I gave from the CRC website references Acts of Synod 1959, 1960, and 1961, and the article I linked references 1959 as the date of the committee. Can you clarify?

Comment: my mistake. The second link I read gave the 68 onwards that is better explanation of their view. I see them to be same as Chicago.